# Caching items from observable until first subscription to deal with race condition

Tags: android, kotlin, reactive-programming, rx-java2

I am using Reactive Extensions (RxJava 2) to perform an RPC call to a Bluetooth device, resulting in an incoming data stream, which I subsequently parse, also uxing Rx. The resulting API is a simple `Flowable<DownloadedRecord>`. For this, I am building on top of the [Rx API of the Sweetblue library for Android](https://sweetblue.io/docs/Getting-Started-Rx).

**My problem is there is a race condition between 'requesting' the device to start streaming, and subscribing to the stream in time to make sure no packets are missed.**

I use a `Completable` to first perform an RPC call to request data streaming to commence, `andThen( readRecords )`. A race condition seems to occur where some packets are emitted by Sweetblue, before `readRecords` had time to subscribe to this stream, thereby 'breaking' `readRecords`.

To abstract away from this concrete scenario, take the following stand alone code:

```
val numbers = PublishSubject.create<Int>()

var currentTotal = 0
val sumToTen = numbers
    .doOnNext { currentTotal += it }
    .doOnNext { println( "Produced $it" ) }
    .takeUntil { currentTotal >= 10 }
    .doOnComplete { println( "Produced a total of $currentTotal." ) }

Completable.fromAction { numbers.onNext( 9 ) } ) // Mimic race condition.
    .andThen( sumToTen )
    .subscribe { println( "Observed: $it, Current total: $currentTotal" ) }

numbers.onNext( 1 )
```

The `numbers.onNext( 9 )` call mimics the race condition. This number is never observed by `sumToTen`, since `sumToTen` is only subscribed to on the next line. Thus, the stream never completes.

After some investigating, I understand I can 'solve' this problem by using `replay` and `connect`.

```
val numbers = PublishSubject.create<Int>()

var currentTotal = 0
val sumToTen = numbers
    .doOnNext { currentTotal += it }
    .doOnNext { println( "Produced $it" ) }
    .takeUntil { currentTotal >= 10 }
    .doOnComplete { println( "Produced a total of $currentTotal." ) }
    .replay( 1 ) // Always replay last item upon subscription.

Completable.fromAction { sumToTen.connect() }
    .andThen( Completable.fromAction { numbers.onNext( 9 ) } )
    .andThen( sumToTen )
    .subscribe { println( "Observed: $it, Current total: $currentTotal" ) }

numbers.onNext( 1 )
```

Now the `sumToTen` stream completes, since, by first connecting to `sumToThen` prior to 'starting to stream data' (`onNext( 9 )`), this stream subscribes to `numbers`, thus the intended side effects occur (`currentTotal`). **But**, '9' is only observed when the `replay` buffer is big enough (in this case it is). For example, replacing `replay( 1 )` with `publish` will make the stream complete ("Produced a total of 10"), but will not observe '9'.

I am not fully satisfied with this solution for two reasons:

1. This simply minimizes the chance of the race condition occurring. How large to set the `replay` buffer is arbitrary.
2. This will always keep the specified number of elements in `replay` in memory, even though the intent is only to do so until subscribed to.

Practically speaking neither of these are a real problem, but this is an eye soar from a maintainability perspective: *the code does not clearly communicate the intent*.

Is there a better way to deal with this scenario? E.g.:

- A `replay` operator which only replays for one subscriber (thus drops the cache once emitted for the first time).
- An entirely different approach than what I explored here with `publish/connect`?

Comment: Hi, I have a similar Problem. Did you ever find a solution for it?

Comment: @Daniel82 not other than the described solutions.